# No such file or directory - identify with Mini Magick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, minimagick

my rails app was running smoothly before I had another person re-do my front-end UI. I've been trying to resolve this error for 3 days now. Here is the error:

````
No such file or directory - identify

Extracted source (around line #59):
57
58
59
60
61
62

    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    authorize @post
    if @post.update_attributes(post_params)
      flash[:notice] = "Post was updated."
      redirect_to [@topic, @post]
    else

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"patch",
 "authenticity_token"=>"A817ZJp/WMHt+U0ROTvVFs8OMZCz6MbF9/pDSa9ZDWo=",
 "post"=>{"title"=>"Zouk Club",
 "body"=>"Testing a new post\r\n```\r\nhttp://www.zoukclub.com/\r\n```",
 "tag_list"=>"bar,
 club,
 lifestyle",
 "image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x000001061e1138 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/7b/h8rkx52141z_4xj_0yzbsdjw0000gn/T/RackMultipart20141111-25635-i2v4vj>,
 @original_filename="zouk3.jpg",
 @content_type="image/jpeg",
 @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"post[image]\"; filename=\"zouk3.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">},
 "commit"=>"Save",
 "topic_id"=>"1",
 "id"=>"1"}
````

I've tried updated Mini Magick and downgrading it to 3.50 as proposed by the other posts on Stack Overflow, but I am still running into this issue.

Anyone know what the issue might be? I am kinda lost here...

Comment: what happens when you type 'which identity' into your terminal and what operating system are you on?

Comment: Nothing happens when I type which identity, I am running Yosemite on my MacBook Air

Comment: Sorry, I meant to ask what happened when you type 'which identify', not 'which identity'. Trying to find out whether or not identify is installed on your machine.

Comment: Hmm nothing happens..doesn't give me anything, I tried identify -version as well, and got a command not found error.

Comment: Are you certain that you have ImageMagick installed? Sounds like that might be the problem.

Comment: Hmm okay this is weird, it seems that I didn't have it installed. I installed it and now I am running into the following error:       Expected(200) <=> Actual(403 Forbidden) response => #<Excon::Response:0x000001054162d8 @data={:body=>"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<Error><Code>InvalidAccessKeyId</Code><Message>The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.

Comment: Never mind i got it to work! So installing ImageMagick resolved the issue.... Thanks @NickM

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to install ImageMagick. Try running:

```
which identify
```

If nothing comes back you probably don't have `ImageMagick` installed.